# regular expression boost library regex_search match error

Tags: c++, boost

when i use boost::regex_search function to do something like this

```
std::string sTest = "18";
std::string sRegex = "^([\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+)(\\d+)(#?)$";
std::string::const_iterator iterStart = sTest.begin();
std::string::const_iterator iterEnd = sTest.end();
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> RegexResults;

while (boost::regex_search(iterStart, iterEnd, RegexResults, boost::regex(sRegex)))
{
    int a = 1;
    break; 
}
```

however value 'stest' is matched,but when i use std::regex_search it's ok.

Comment: That's a beast of a question, though it looks innocent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the question is serious:

the regex matches

0. `^` (start of input)
1. What looks like you intended as one or more of the ["CJK Unified Ideographs"
   block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block)) (though only from the 1.0.1 Unicode standard).

   However, this is not what is parsed. (Instead, indeed it parses as regular hex escapes which does match `1`).

   The
   [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.escapes)
   tell me that you might have wanted `\x{dddd}` but that requires
   Unicode support.

   Digging in more [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html) tell me that

   > *There are two ways to use Boost.Regex with Unicode strings:*
   >
   > #### Rely on wchar_t
   >
   > (lists a bunch of limitations and conditions)
   >
   > #### Use a Unicode Aware Regular Expression Type.

   May I suggest the latter
2. one or more numerical digits (according to the locale's character classicification)
3. `(#?)` might have been intended as a comment (`(?#)`) but as spelled optionally matches a single `#` character
4. followed by `$` (end of input)

That's not in your input, so it shouldn't match.

### Off Topic?

Besides, since this is a fully anchored pattern (`^$`) it would only make sense
with `regex_match`, not `regex_search`.

The while loop is a weird idea, because the input never changes, so neither will
the search result. If there's a match, the loop always breaks. Your `while` amounts to a more confusing `if` statement.

### The Fix

Here's a program that codes three switchable approaches with three different regexes.

The approaches are BOOST_SIMPLE, BOOST_UNICODE and STANDARD_LIB.

The first regex is yours, the second with `\x{XXXX}` escapes instead and the
third is using the named character class `\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}`.

The result is:

- Boost + Unicode approach works correctly (except with your faulty regex)
- Standard library (on my GCC 10 install) as well as Boost Simple **appear** to accept the named character class. I'm doubtful that it actually matches correctly, so I guess it will just fail to match.

### Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fadc9b02d460a8da)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#ifdef STANDARD_LIB
  #include <regex>
  using match = std::smatch;
  using regex = std::regex;
  #define ctor regex
#elif defined(BOOST_SIMPLE)
  #include <boost/regex.hpp>
  using match = boost::smatch;
  using regex = boost::regex;
  #define ctor regex
#elif defined(BOOST_UNICODE)
  #include <boost/regex/icu.hpp>
  using match = boost::smatch;
  using regex = boost::u32match;
  #define ctor        boost::make_u32regex
  #define regex_match boost::u32regex_match
#else
  #error "Need to pick a flavour"
#endif

int main() {
    std::string const sTest = "18";

    struct testcase { std::string_view label, re; };

    for (auto current : { testcase
        { "wrong unicode character class",
            R"(^([\u4E00-\u9FA5]+)(\d+)(#?)$)" },
        { "correct unicode character class",
            R"(^([\x{4E00}-\x{9FA5}]+)(\d+)(#?)$)" },
        { "named character class",
            R"(^([\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}]+)(\d+)(#?)$)" },
    }) {
        std::cout
            << std::string(current.label.length(), '=') << "\n"
            << current.label << " (" << std::quoted(current.re) << ")\n";

        try {
            match results;
            bool is_match = regex_match(sTest, results, ctor(current.re.data()));

            std::cout << "is_match: " << std::boolalpha << is_match << "\n";
            if (is_match) {
                std::cout << "$1: " << std::quoted(results[1].str()) << "\n";
                std::cout << "$2: " << std::quoted(results[2].str()) << "\n";
                std::cout << "$3: " << std::quoted(results[3].str()) << "\n";
            }
        } catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "failure: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling with

```
g++ -DBOOST_SIMPLE  -O2 -std=c++17 main.cpp -lboost_regex -o boost_simple
g++ -DBOOST_UNICODE -O2 -std=c++17 main.cpp -lboost_regex -o boost_unicode -licuuc
g++ -DSTANDARD_LIB  -O2 -std=c++17 main.cpp -o Standard_lib
```

Has outputs:

- File `boost_simple.log`

  ```
   =============================
   wrong unicode character class ("^([\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: true
   $1: "1"
   $2: "8"
   $3: ""
   ===============================
   correct unicode character class ("^([\\x{4E00}-\\x{9FA5}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   failure: Hexadecimal escape sequence was invalid.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '^([>>>HERE>>>\x{4E00}-\'.
   =====================
   named character class ("^([\\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: false
  ```
- File `boost_unicode.log`

  ```
   =============================
   wrong unicode character class ("^([\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: true
   $1: "1"
   $2: "8"
   $3: ""
   ===============================
   correct unicode character class ("^([\\x{4E00}-\\x{9FA5}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: false
   =====================
   named character class ("^([\\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: false
  ```
- File `standard_lib.log`

  ```
   =============================
   wrong unicode character class ("^([\\u4E00-\\u9FA5]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   failure: Invalid range in bracket expression.
   ===============================
   correct unicode character class ("^([\\x{4E00}-\\x{9FA5}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   failure: Unexpected end of regex when ascii character.
   =====================
   named character class ("^([\\p{InCJK_Unified_Ideographs}]+)(\\d+)(#?)$")
   is_match: false
  ```